# How to encrypted a File in adobe air

Tags: file-io, air, encryption

How to encrypt a file using adobe air... and if i have encrypted it, how to decrypt it again ..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use as3crypto. get it from http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/